# Unable to understand XPath siblings behaviour

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a HTML page in an scenario where I only have consecutive tags with information.

From the following code I would like to get the text for the  tags (e.g. Name1, Name2, ...), taking into consideration:

"a" followed by "span" gives information about that ID being a Customer or not.

"a" followed by "a" means that ID is anonymous.

```
<span class="list">
    <em>List 1:</em>
</span>
<a href="/ID/423006">Name1</a>, 
<a href="/ID/115325">Name2</a>
<span class="small">(Customer)</span>, 
<a href="/ID/248819">Name3</a>
<span class="small">(Non Customer)</span>, 
<a href="/ID/658259">Name4</a>
<span class="small">(Customer)</span>, 
<a href="/ID/294083">Name5</a>
<a href="/ID/218292">Name6</a>
<span class="small">(Non Customer)</span>
```

I'm using the following XPATH to try to match "a" followed by "span"

> //a[contains(@href,'ID/') and ./following-sibling::span[1][text() = '(Customer)']]/text()

This will return Name1, Name2 and Name4, even if Name1 is not a Customer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the first following-sibling span of that Name1 does indeed equal "(Customer)".

What you should do instead is find the first following sibling (`*[1]`) and check to see if that sibling is a `span` (`[self::span]`) and if it is, then check to see if it's equal to "(Customer)"...

```xml
//a[contains(@href,'ID/') and ./following-sibling::*[1][self::span][text() = '(Customer)']]/text()
```